# Set variable during a query

Tags: mysql, grafana

Have the following query

```
SELECT 
Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date',
device_serial as "Device Serial",
customer_name as "Customer",
error_code as 'Error Code',
resolutiom as 'Resolution'
FROM preventive_maintenance
ORDER BY `timestamp` desc
LIMIT 25
```

I want to order by 'Due Date' that was randomed, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just make your current query as a sub query.

```
SELECT 
    T.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as `Due Date`,
        device_serial as `Device Serial`,
        customer_name as `Customer`,
        error_code as `Error Code`,
        resolutiom as `Resolution`
    FROM preventive_maintenance
        -- ORDER BY `timestamp` desc
    LIMIT 25) AS T
ORDER BY T.`Due Date`
```

Comment: Something is not working well in the ORDER BY, I want the nearest days to be on top

Comment: @user829174 your `as 'due date'` is incorrect in sql. field names must be encapsulated in ```` not " or '. See the edits

Comment: when copy/paste to Grafana I get:
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Customer, error_code as Error Code, resolutiom as `Resolutio' at line 6

Comment: @user829174 there is a ` missing after `as customer`. You should be able to spot simple mistakes like these :)

Comment: when pasting in workbench, results are displayed well. when paste to grafana results are not ordered correctly... do you have any idea?

Comment: might the problem be that 'Due Date` a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
Order By `Due Date`
```

needs to work. Did you try it? If it doesn't you can use subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
      Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date',
      device_serial as "Device Serial",
      customer_name as "Customer",
      error_code as 'Error Code',
      resolutiom as 'Resolution'
    FROM preventive_maintenance
) T
ORDER BY `Due Date`
LIMIT 25
```

---

Demonstration

> ```
> SELECT * from (
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> union all 
> SELECT  Now() + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-5+1)+5) DAY as 'Due Date' from dual
> ) T
> order by `Due Date`
> LIMIT 5
> ```
>
> ```
> | Due Date            |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2019-10-27 13:16:15 |
> | 2019-11-26 13:16:15 |
> | 2020-05-05 13:16:15 |
> | 2020-07-01 13:16:15 |
> | 2020-07-01 13:16:15 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6f6029e14c7d46a4f4b38bfad0fda17)*

Comment: Something is not working well in the ORDER BY, I want the nearest days to be on top

Comment: Is it possible to create example fiddle which demonstrates issue on https://dbfiddle.uk/?

Comment: it works well in fiddle, something with Grafa which I'm using, might the problem be that 'Due Date` a string?